# Graphlab installing error in windows 8.1

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, graphlab

I downloaded the Graphlab installer from [here](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create.html) and tried to install in my computer.But I changed the directory of its installation to anaconda3 though Anaconda2 is also installed in my computer.But the installation ended with error.Then I uninstalled Anaconda2,Anacond3 and deleted all files associated with Graphlab from my computer.Later I reinstalled those and tried to install it to Anacaonda 2 but I found the following error:

"There was a problem activating the gl-env conda environment.  Restart GraphLab Create Launcher.

> Unable to activate conda environment "gl-env":
>       Deactivating environment "C:\Anaconda2"... Activating environment "C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env"... The input line is too long. 
>   "PATH_NO_SCRIPTS=C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env;C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\Scripts;C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda2;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;H:\IDE\Kornodo\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Perl64\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\runtime\win64;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\polyspace\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\File Viewer
>   Lite\lib\magick;C:\Anaconda3\Library\binC:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;H:\IDE\Kornodo\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;F:\Game
>   development\UNreal engine;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;H:\IDE\Kornodo\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;F:\Game
>   development\UNreal engine;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27" was unexpected at this
>   time.
>
> Process completed with exit code -1"

I restarted GraphLab Create Launcher several times.I tried to install it from cmd according to this [link](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html) but it also shows the above error when I try to activate gl-env.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it appears that it is due to the PATH environment variable is too long.

Try shortening it ensuring the anaconda path remains.

Make sure you back up your old path first though.

I am using win 7 so you may need to google how to edit your PATH variable.

On Win 7:

Click start

Right click Computer -> select properties

Click Advanced system settings

In the dialog that appears at the bottom click Environment Variables

In the System Variables group highlight Path and click edit

Copy the entire Variable Value and paste into notepad. Save this as your backup so you can revert back, then delete anything that may not be relevant and paste back into the Variable value.

Click on all of the OK's and close and re-open your command prompt. These changes won't take affect until you do so.

Hope this helps

G